# UPDATE statement with FORMULA in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have my code here which shows how to update a certain field in sql table. It works perfectly fine but I want to add a formula where it reads each row on the table then updates the field at the same time.

I have here a table named "TimeTable".
From this table, I have 3 datafields named "hours", "rate" and "regularRate".
Formula for getting regularRate is: regularRate = hours * rate

Problem is I dont know how to get the datafields "hours" and "rate" to formulate it then update the regulaRrate. Pls help. Im just a beginner.

```
myCon.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = myCon;
com.CommandText = "UPDATE TimeTable SET regularRate=@regularRate";

double regRate = convert.toDouble(@hours) * convert.toDouble(@rate);
com.Parameters.Add("@regularRate", SqlDbType.Float).Value = regRate;

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCon.Close();
```

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP - can you retag, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need variables or parameters here. You just need

```
UPDATE TimeTable
SET    regularRate = hours * rate;
```

Though why are you storing this at all? If it can be calculated this formula-icly you can use a (non persisted) computed column if SQL Server.

Or use a view with this computation in other DBMSs

Answer (score 0):

```
 com.CommandText = "UPDATE TimeTable SET regularRate = convert(Double,hours) * convert(Double,rate)"
```